# DNS setting to access website using IP address and domain name

Tags: dns, static-ip-address

I have Static IP, i would like to access website using static IP as well using domain name.

I have below DNS entries to for my domain, i am not sure what setup i need to do to make it works.

when user access my site using domain name they should be able to access. Also when someone want to access using IP address they should be able to do that.

```
www    14400  IN CNAME example.com
example.com 14400  IN A 50.63.147.111
```

If anybody have idea please let me know.

Thank you

Regards,
Mona

Comment: can anybody tell me please why - votes.. if dont have capability of answering my doubt surly you dont have rights to - vote... god bless you.. - voters..

Comment: The question probably belongs at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't access your IP address, then it isn't because of your DNS. DNS stands for domain name system and translates domain names TO IP addresses. Thus, you must already have a reachable IP address for your A record to be meaningful. Make sure that you've configured your server correctly (Apache?) and that the necessary ports are open in your firewall (iptables).

Check that your domain registrar is pointing its name servers to the authoritative name server (the server with your zone file) for your domain.